# dtreeviz python package is showing a split as being at 0 instead of the actual number

Tags: python, dtreeviz

The dtreeviz python package is showing a split at .216 as "0.000" as seen in this screenshot:
[image]

The code is:

```
self.clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234, max_depth=self.treeDepth)
viz_model = dtreeviz.model(self.clf,
                                   X_train=self.features, y_train=self.target,
                                   feature_names=self.featureColumns,
                                   target_name=self.targetColumn, class_names=["short", "long"])
v = viz_model.view(scale=2, precision=4)
v.save(path)
```

The textual representation shows the splits correctly:

Code:

```
    text_representation = tree.export_text(self.clf, decimals=3)
```

Output:

```
|--- feature_1 <= 0.216
|   |--- feature_1 <= 0.212
|   |   |--- feature_1 <= 0.208
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- feature_1 >  0.208
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- feature_1 >  0.212
|   |   |--- class: 0
|--- feature_1 >  0.216
|   |--- feature_1 <= 0.401
|   |   |--- feature_1 <= 0.379
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |--- feature_1 >  0.379
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- feature_1 >  0.401
|   |   |--- feature_1 <= 0.430
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- feature_1 >  0.430
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
```